# insert small colored box to the left of a moderncv subsection without using \hspace

Tags: color, moderncv

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\firstname{test}
\familyname{test}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\newcommand{\colsubsection}[1]{\subsection{\hspace{-5mm}%
\textcolor{color1}{%
\rule{2mm}{2mm}}\hspace{2mm} #1}}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\colsubsection{test}
\cvlistitem{test}

\end{document}
```

which produces this as a result:

[image: result]

This method of using `\hspace` doesn't seem very 'stable': The gaps are estimated and therefore not exact, the gaps are hardcoded and therefore easy to break if I change sth in the future. As i don't know how I could improve that code snippet, I'm curious how others would solve that problem.

The Box should be right bound to the blue line of `\section`, which means it should begin (when seen from right direction) at the same width like the `\section` line. Additionally, the gap between the color box to the text 'test' should be equal to the gap between the colored line of `\section` to the text 'test'. The position in y direction (the vertical gap) between `\subsection` and any other command should remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why do you define a custom subsection command and not just redefine the default? To me it would make more sense to redefine it. Next thing I did was looking up the section/subsection definitions in moderncv. They are as follows:

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{}{\strut\subsectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
```

If you combine the two and make the adjustments you want, you end up with something like this. Be aware that my rect is a bit smaller, as it has exactly the same height as the `section` bar.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\firstname{Firstname}
\familyname{Surname}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{0.3ex}{\color{color1}\rule{0.95ex}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\subsectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\cvlistitem{Item}

\end{document}
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

[image: moderncv]

Comment: I used a new definition because I've read that this should be favoured instead of redefinition. Thanks!